# root of quadratic equation in $Z_n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I want to find criterion on $n$ satisfying this statement:

"there is $x \in \mathbb{Z} _n$ such that $x^2 = a$".

In case that $a=-1$, it is well known that

(1) if $4k+1$ is prime, $n=4k+1$ satisfy the statement.

(2) if $4k+3$ if prime, $n=4k+3$ can't satisfy the statement.

In case that n is not prime and a is not -1, is there simple criterion?

Comment: For $n$ a product of prime powers, the answer can be put together by considering the prime powers. But even for odd prime $n$, the full theory is fairly complicated. Please see Legendre symbol, quadratic reciprocity.

Comment: This just comes down to properties of quadratic characters right? (by that I mean the legendre symbol)

Comment: If $\gcd(n,a)=1$, reduce the problem into the case where $n$ is a prime power.  Show that, for an integer $k>0$, for an odd prime $p$ with $\gcd(p,a)=1$, $x^2=a$ has a solution with $x\in\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}$ if and only if $x^2=a$ has a solution with $x\in\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.  Then, you deal with $n=2^k$ individually.  You can deal with the case $\gcd(n,a)\neq 1$, too, but it is slightly more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

For $n=p$ prime, you can use [Euler's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion):
$$
a^{\tfrac{p-1}{2}} \equiv 1 \bmod p
\iff
\text{$x^2 \equiv a \bmod p$ has a solution}
$$
when $p$ does not divide $a$. When $p$ does divide $a$, then $x^2 \equiv a $ has a solution $x=0$.